# Deleting a comment with the "add comment" textarea open, removes the textarea

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

I found a rather interesting bug with the comments.  Here's what I did.

1. Add a comment to a post.
2. Click "add comment", the text box opens
3. Delete the previous comment

The comment *and* the text box for new comments are *both* removed!  This only seems to happen when the comment I am deleting is the <strike>last and</strike> only comment.

Comment: I was able to repro this. Good catch.

Comment: ... making it impossible to add a comment without refreshing the page, since the "add comment" button is also gone.

Comment: @Dukeling: Can you reproduce this? While researching another issue I found this but can't reproduce it any longer, but it may have to do with me being a moderator.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Yes I can. [Visualized steps to reproduce](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190680/206447).

Comment: I was also able to reproduce it

Comment: What browser(s) does this happen in?

Comment: @Emil Reproduces for me on Chrome 28 and IE 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've marked this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).  Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Visualized steps to reproduce on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152869/206447)...

First click to add a comment:

[image]

Then add it:

[image]

Then click to add another:

[image]

Then delete the first comment:

[image]

Then the comment-adding ability is gone:

[image]

Comment: OK I just tried it here and it does not appear to affect me as a moderator. That said, [something else does](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190682/as-a-moderator-viewing-deleted-comments-on-a-post-causes-its-add-comment-link).

Comment: I can't reproduce it...

Comment: Reproduces on Chrome 28 and IE 10, so I doubt it's browser-specific.

Comment: Doesn't reproduce for me in Chrome 28 on a Mac, so it must be something-specific, right?

Comment: Scratch that, it reproduces, but only on answers with no other comments.