# As a moderator, viewing deleted comments on a post causes its "add comment" link to disappear

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, moderator-tools

Now that deleted comments are displayed beneath a post instead of in a separate page when I click to view them, doing so causes the "add comment" link for the post in question to disappear until I refresh the page.

Strangely, as a moderator I cannot reproduce this issue with the steps described [in a similar report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170963/deleting-a-comment-with-the-add-comment-textarea-open-removes-the-textarea); my ability to view deleted comments inline triggers it instead.

Comment: I cannot reproduce either as a normal user or a moderator.

Comment: Ahh, the problems of the ruling class.

Comment: @AsheeshR: When you click the "View deleted comments" the "Add comment" link disappears. I managed to reproduce as a mod.

Comment: Reproed on Physics. No comments were harmed in the enactment of this experiment; the moderator instead autopsied comments which had already been baleetinated.

Comment: Reproed on Chem too

Comment: The 'Add comment' link disappears for the slightest reason. Vote to close? Link disappears. Deleted a comment? Link gone. etc. It is *bloody irritating*.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn yes it's disappearing for me also, it seems to like being refreshed (maybe it feels dirty somehow??)

Comment: Also repro'd on dba.SE - but not in all cases. I visited a question that already had deleted comments, and clicking on that link did not make the `add comment` link disappear. However, on another question, which didn't already have any deleted comments, I intentionally added a comment, then deleted it, left the page, and came back. This time, when I clicked the `1 deleted comment` link, the `add comment` link disappeared. Perhaps this has something to do with the new `undelete` form of comment?

Comment: Hmm, I cannot reproduce this behavior.  Does it occur on this specific post for you, when viewing the three deleted comments?

Comment: @Jarrod Dixon: I missed your comment somehow. I can no longer reproduce this behavior today - not sure if it's because [the other issue was just fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170963/deleting-a-comment-with-the-add-comment-textarea-open-removes-the-textarea), but given that you couldn't reproduce it a day after I reported it it might not have been the case. Either way, it works now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like fixing other related issues has resolved this one as well.  Cheers!